# Connecting AWS API Endpoint to Salesforce to Apex REST

Tags: apexrest, amazon-aws

My company tasked me to look into end-to-end event flow between AWS and Salesforce using the newly released [Event Relay](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.ev_relay_intro.htm&type=5). I successfully followed the guide, sent CDC events from Salesforce to AWS, and got some responses back from AWS. However, I achieved that using the platform events on Salesforce as my API Destination (https://XXXX.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v58.0/sobjects/AWS_Enrich_test__e). Now I am trying to take it a step further and expose an APEX Class as a web service (using @RestResource annotation). I have configured a new API Destination on AWS, but nothing comes through, like debug logs not even showing my class being called. (https://r7--qa.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/awsUpdateEvent).

I tested this class with the Postman and was able to receive data and do the DMLs on the records, however, when I try it with AWS rules that are sending data to this API destination, nothing happens.

I have the Connected App up and running, and here is my Class:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/awsUpdateEvent/*')
global with sharing class InboundAWSEventResource {
    @HttpPost 
    global static String processInboundEvent () {
        // Retrieve the JSON payload from the request
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        String requestBody = req.requestBody.toString();
        InboundEventWrapper eventWrapper = (InboundEventWrapper)JSON.deserialize(requestBody, InboundEventWrapper.class);
        InboundEventPayload payload = eventWrapper.payload;
        System.debug('payload >> '+payload);
        
        String entityName = payload.eventType;
        String recordId = payload.recordId;
        if (recordId.startsWith('a2J')){
            String changeType = payload.changeType;
            String entryId = payload.entryId;
            String outboundEventNumber = payload.outboundEventNumber;
            String orderId = payload.orderId;
            
            String targetSystemEventStatus = payload.targetSystemEventStatus;
            String targetSystemErrorMessage = payload.targetSystemErrorMessage;
            // Process the values as needed
            try {
                List <OutboundEvent__c> record = [SELECT Id,TargetSystemErrorMessage__c,TargetSystemEventStatus__c
                                                FROM OutboundEvent__c 
                                                WHERE id =:recordId LIMIT 1 ];
                record[0].TargetSystemEventStatus__c = targetSystemEventStatus;
                record[0].TargetSystemErrorMessage__c = targetSystemErrorMessage;
                update record;
            } catch(DmlException e) {
                System.debug('The following exception has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        else {}
        // Return a response if needed
        RestContext.response.statusCode = 200;
        RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('Event processed successfully');
        String result = 'Success! for entity '+entityName;
        return result;
    }
     
    // Inner classes for deserialization
    global class InboundEventWrapper {
        public String entityName;
        public InboundEventPayload payload;
    }
    
    global class InboundEventPayload {
        public String changeType;
        public String eventType;
        public String entryId;
        public String outboundEventNumber;
        public String orderId;
        public String recordId;
        public String targetSystemEventStatus;
        public String targetSystemErrorMessage;
    }
}
```

What am I missing?